# What's wrong with these datapicker?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm triyng to implement a datapicker in my form view,

Here's is the form:

```
$builder
    ->add('startdate', DateType::class, [
        'attr' => [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'class' => 'js-datepicker',
            'html5' => false,
        ]
    ])
```

My view _form

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="startdate">{% trans into lang %}Start date, not working day{% endtrans %}</label>
    {{ form_widget(form.startdate) }}
    </div>
```

And my function in the view

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-datepicker').datepicker();
    });
});
```

As you can see, still rendering the input as inputs, not as text, what i'm doing wrong?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Xdc.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`widget` and `html5` should not be in `attr`:

```
$builder
    ->add('startdate', DateType::class, [
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'html5' => false,
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'js-datepicker',
        ]
    ])
```